# What is the best approach to add translatable field for curly quote start and end sign in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal-8

## “This is a sample text 1 for English.”

## „This is a sample text 2 for German.“

I want to make start and end sign configurable and translatable. I want same for both custom block and paragraph type in Drupal 8.

Comment: Remove "best" from title. Just select from the answers what you like best.

Comment: @U.Windl Could you help me to choose the best answer?

Comment: Well ,you'll have to wait for answers, still...